# Darkend area after Make Edge/Face

Tags: modeling, faces

When I try to make faces from non manifold edges the edge of the model is darkens.

[image]
[image]

I see the same affect on Unity 3D when I import .blender files. When I add a material to the model the affect doesnt change and the color of the corners stays darkened. How can I prevent this?